# How to access a member of a class when it is stored as a object of a parent class that has no such method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a hierarchy such as:

```
Element
|_Resitance
|_DC Voltage Source
|_AC Voltage Source
|_AC Current Source
|_DC Current Source
|_DynamicElement
|  |_Inductor
|  |_Capacitor
|_SwitchingDevices
|  |_Switch
|  |_Diode
.
.
.
```

As my input can be any a list of those, they are all inserted in a `std::vector<Element*>`. The problem is that Diode, Switch and the Voltage sources have a ID member that I have to access.

I want to be able to run a *(*Element).ID or something like this, when I'm sure that the Element is a subclass with such member.

I really don't want to include ID member in the Element class because this is something that is going to happen a lot an the class would have a lot of inappropriate member.

Comment: So you want to [*downcast*](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php) the `Element*` to e.g. a `Switch*`?

Comment: I was not familiar with this term and, for what I read, yes. I could create a new pointer with the new class and destroy said pointer afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add virtual destructor to base class and use `dynamic_cast<>` to derived class to access its members. `dynamic_cast` by reference will throw exception if object is not an instance of the type you cast to and `dynamic_cast` by pointer will return `nullptr` in same case.

Example:

```
class Element
{
    ...
    virtual ~Element() = default;
};

...

Element * el = new Diode();
Diode * d = dynamic_cast<Diode *>(el);
if (d) {
// ok, this is diode
}
```

Comment: Does this delete ```el```(why do you need the destructor?)? I need not to intervene in the order of the vector, I have to access the member without changing where ```el``` is saved.

Comment: No, this doesn't delete  `el`, its just create pointer of `Diode *` type to the same instance.

Comment: In that case, why the virtual destructor is necessary?

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` only with classes which has virtual methods table, so such class must contain at least one virtual method, e.g. virtual destructor.

Comment: In my case I have a lot of virtual methods, so I could use without the destructor, is that right?

Comment: You can read more about virtual destructor and why it should be used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: If your derived classes has additional data members you should use virtual destructor to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: This was really helpful because I needed to use it and had no idea! Thanks!